# Materialized Views on AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, materialized-views

I am trying to create a materialized view using different schemas in the same database. But it is not allowing me to create with the error being:
"ERROR: Materialized views cannot be defined on regular or late binding views."

Below is the sql query which I use. Even if the 'schema' is within the database. It still errors out. Any idea?

```
SELECT DISTINCT number as id,
            created_at as date,
            type as dtype
        FROM schema.table1
        WHERE type='Y' AND table1.number NOT IN ('XXXXXXXXXX')
          UNION ALL
        SELECT
            DISTINCT number as id,
            created_at as date,
            type as dtype
        FROM schema.table1
        WHERE type='Y' AND table1.created_at >= '2001-08-01'
          UNION ALL
        SELECT
            DISTINCT number as id,
            created_at as date,
            type as dtype
        FROM schema.table1
        WHERE type='XXXX' AND table1.created_at >= '2001-07-11' AND table1.number NOT IN ('XXXXXXXXXX')
```

But the same query without 'schema' works fine and creates a Materialized View. The table from which I am creating this is not a view and Table which exists in the DB